# Thread.Abort() function is not working in mono framework

Tags: .net, linux, multithreading, mono, window

I am using mono 2.10.8.1 framework to develop one small GUI Standalone application.

I Have created one desktop GUI Application in which i have created one thread which can be used to do  some operation in background and then aborted the calling thread after completing the operation.

One more thing that Abort() function is working  fine in windows without any issue but failed to work in Linux.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(Linux_Thread);
t1.IsBackground = true;
t1.Start();

//Do some operation in some other function.
Console.WriteLine("Linux thread :: " + t1.ThreadState);
t1.Abort();
Console.WriteLine("Linux thread After Abort :: " + t1.ThreadState);
```

SO, The Output of the Above program in Linux is following ::

```
Linux thread :: Background
Linux thread After Abort :: Background, AbortRequested
```

While In windows , The Output of the above program is below ::

```
Linux thread :: Background
Linux thread After Abort :: Stopped
```

So, It seems like that Abort() function is not working in mono framework as it is working in windows platform.

After that, My Application behaves in wrong way due to that abort threading problem and Application goes into hang state.

Does any one have idea about this issue or any one has faced this type of issue?

Is three any alternative way to close the running thread?

Please let me know the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: mono 2.10 is old already, please test with mono 3.2.x

Comment: @knocte :: I am using ubuntu 12.04 and i have seen on "http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html" site that mono 3.2.X is for MAC OS, Windows and Open Suse which is not for other. Do you have idea that they are supporting 3.2.X for other?

Comment: @knocte, Can you please tell me that mono 3.2.X is supported in other Linux Platform except Open Suse?

Comment: if your distro doesn't provide packages for mono 3.2.x, you can compile mono yourself

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Abort is **evil**, it is recommended to avoid it as much as possible.

If you're really sure there is no other way to implement what you want to do, have in mind that aborting a thread is not necessarily instantaneous - in fact it may not happen at all, depending on what the thread you're trying to abort is doing.

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx): "The thread is not guaranteed to abort immediately, or at all. "

Try adding a `t1.Join ()` after the call to `t1.Abort ()` - if it hangs then something might be wrong. In that case you'll need a native stack trace for all threads to see why it's hanging (do get the native stack trace you need to attach gdb: `gdb program <PID>` and then execute (inside gdb): `thread apply all backtrace`.

Comment: I have tried the way by abort and join as you are telling but the result is that GUI goes into hang state after using that way..

Comment: so, It seems that join is not the proper way to solve this issue.

Comment: If it hangs when using Join please get a stack trace using gdb as I explained.

Comment: Is there any issue causes if i comment out the Abort() function as i have observed that Linux will manage by itself and exit the running thread at the end of completion of that thread.

Comment: I have commented out the t1.Abort() line every where wherever i used in my code and ran that code with some possible test-cases which is running fine without any memory related or other issues which i have faced whenever i used Abort() function. Does this process causes any issues from memory as well as some other issues in Linux side?

Comment: It is quite hard to write code that takes into account Abort exceptions (since they can happen almost at any time), so it is definitively possible that using Abort leads to memory issues in your app.